# TFS 2015 API for machine Groups

Tags: tfs

I have had no luck identifying or finding anyone mention in posts, articles etc. for the location in the TFS 2015 API for accessing the machine groups a.k.a test machine groups.

If anyone has any knowledge of this if you could point me in the correct direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine Groups is a new concept in TFS2015. It's a logical grouping of machines. The Machine Group holds metadata, connectivity, and login details of the machines in the group. Machine Group can directly be referenced from build and release definitions. However, there is no related api to access them for now.

The build agent uses **Windows PowerShell** remoting that requires the Windows Remote Management (**WinRM**) **protocol** to connect to the machines in the Machine Groups. More details please take a look at this blog:[TFS 2015 Machine Groups - Walkthrough](http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/blog/teamfoundationserver/HowToConfigureTFSMachineGroupsOnPremAndUseWithTFBuildRelease)

Comment: Awww... Patrick that is saddening. You guys always talk up and tell us that the public TFS API is the same API you use internally (used  to always say that at least). Since there is no API now for them as they existed in Update 2 we can know there never will be as they are already to be replaced by by a more proper implementation. Sad about the answer but glad you took the time to answer it.